# Nginx locations and nested Slim indexes

Tags: php, nginx, slim

Using php Slim framework and having the following structure:

```
/root
    /dir_parent_1/
        /dir_child_1
            /index.php
    /dir_parent_2
        /index.php
```

`/root/dir_parent_1/dir_child_1/index.php` have the `users` route, and
`/root/dir_parent_2/index.php` have the `clients` route.

How i write the Nginx location to match the two possible combinations?

I try:

```
location ~ ^/root/(\w+)
{
    try_files $uri /gestionhospitales/api/$1/index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ ^/root/(\w+)/(\w+)
{
    try_files $uri /gestionhospitales/api/$1/$2/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

But they are mutually excluding. Going to "/root/dir_parent_1/dir_child_1/users" match the first rule (because it is first. If i invert the order, the second is matched),

Also i started to write a rule for both cases, but i don't know how to finish it:

```
location ~ ^/root/(\w+)?/(\w*)
{
    try_files $uri /gestionhospitales/api/$1/$2/index.php?$query_string;
#  tried with if, rewrite, etc. But i'm not nginx expert.
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nginx priority location doesn't depend on the the order, it chooses the *longest* path among declared locations first off, read through [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and please update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only route you have to setup is to forward everything to index.php file in your public directory.

```
root         /path/www.mysite.com/public_html;

try_files $uri /index.php;
```

This file should contains the php code to boostrap Slim Framework. Then all "routes" will be handled by PHP and Slim according to your code in index.php and not by nginx.

```
$app->get('/users', function () {
    echo "This is the user route!";
});

$app->get('/clients', function () {
    echo "This is the client route!";
});
```

You can see a complete example [here](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/) in the official documentation.

Comment: Seems this is the correct way. I wanted to separate indexes to avoid requiring unnecessary files, but that is a kind of early optimization that i'll implement in the near future.

Many thanks.